# Azure Devops Piepeline - Yaml Powershell Script Path

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I would like to ask you if someone knows how to create a correct path to powershell in Azure Devops Pipeline Yaml Syntax.

How looks like my YAML (Currently):

```
trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    filePath: './scripts/script.ps1'
```

How looks like my directory:

[image]

What kind of path returns the pipeline:

> Get-Content: /home/vsts/work/1/s/scripts/script.ps1:12

What kind of error returns the pipeline:

> ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct answer:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    filePath: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s/scripts/script.ps1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Would need to see how your publish task looks like and what the relative path looks like. Try adding `-powershell Get-ChildItem -Path $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) -recurse` This will list out all the paths so you can see what the full path to your script is.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to ask you if someone knows how to create a correct path
> to powershell in Azure Devops Pipeline Yaml Syntax.

It's not that PS can't find your script, instead the error message indicates there's something wrong with the line12 in your xx.ps1 file.

I can't locate the issue until you share the content of the script here. My suggestion is that you should run the pipeline again with `System.Debug=true` to get the detailed error message, you should get the hint there.